# How can I create a Zend Controller Test Case with Zend Studio?

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit, zend-studio

I want to create a Zend Controller Test Case with Zend Studio 7.0.

(from Zend documentation)
"To create a new Zend Controller Test Case:
   1. In PHP Explorer view, right-click the Controller file containing the classes you would like to test and select New | Zend Framework Item | Zend Controller Test Case."

But I can see only "Zend Controller (Template Based)" and "Zend Controller (Zend Tool Based)", no "Zend Controller Test Case"!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you looking for is a PHPUnit Test Case.

To get there assuming you have the default setting on your Zend Studio follow the following steps:

1.Right Click on the controller.

2.Go to New->Other->PHP->PHPUnit->PHPUnit Test Case.

Answer (score 0):

You can also click in the PHP Explorer window, hit ctrl-2, which will open the Zend_Tool window, cd into the project and type "zf create controller "